# ASP.NET Validators only do date compare check if valid date time

Tags: asp.net, validation, datetime

So at the moment I have these 3 Validators

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="dashboardFromDateDateCheck" runat="server" ValidationExpression="[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]" 
ControlToValidate="filterFromDate" ErrorMessage="Invalid From Date Format, (mm/dd/yyyy)" Text="*"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator> 

<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="dashboardToDateDateCheck" runat="server" ValidationExpression="[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]" 
ControlToValidate="filterToDate" ErrorMessage="Invalid To Date Format, (mm/dd/yyyy)" Text="*"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator> 

<asp:CompareValidator ID="checkDashboardFilterDateRange" runat="server" ControlToValidate="filterFromDate" ControlToCompare="filterToDate" Type="Date"
Operator="LessThanEqual" ErrorMessage="From Date must be before To Date" Text="*"/>
```

But I only want the compare validator to work if both dates are valid and if both dates are entered. Because in my search they are allowed to leave the dates blank or only enter a from or to date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

drop your `CompareValidator` and add a `CustomValidator`. With the `CustomValidator` you will be able to implement the logic you want.

and if you wanted you could technically throw the other two validators into your `CustomValidator`, but I would leave those two separate.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to work for me.  It lets me through if I leave one or both fields blank.  Otherwise the validation works.  Hmm.

Comment: if you enter invalid datetime, the compare message shows. If you enter a from date but no to date the compare shows and other way around. I only want to show if both dates are entered, and are valid datetimes and from date is greater than to date.

Comment: I assumed you were using a datepicker to assure a valid date.  Also if I enter the from date, but no to date, it lets me pass.